# MVC ExternalLoginConfirmation and registering username

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, facebook-login, google-signin

When users in an MVC application with Google/Facebook/Twitter authentication, register for the first time, they go to the ExternalLoginConfirmation.cshtml page. There they are asked for their username, but are only allowed to fill in an email address, according to the ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model.

Is it set to email for a reason? In code it's creating a new applicationuser to store the user, but it's using just-entered-email for both username & email.

Can I go horribly wrong when I allow users to enter username of their choosing, and store email address as I got it from Google/Facebook/Twitter, etc?

Comment: What's the exact question - should you let users choose their own username/email?

Answer (score 3):

I think the MVC5 registration flow is flawed by default, and needs to be reworked.

1. by trusting the default provider's emails (set email is auto confirmed from Google+, Yahoo, MS, and Facebook).
2. don't let the user enter an email+username, as he can register ANY email he enters in the box, straight to the AppUsers table.
3. MVC5 needs to create a User if not done so already at the ExternalLoginConfirmation method.
4. the default login password would be set to something blank, with links to reset it if needed (or totally disabled).

This would allow the users to register on any massively trusted providers automatically, it would link accounts together as long as their email is the same, and allow to unlink accounts once again.

The way MVC5 is setup right now is half-baked and broken, for no apparent reason.

Comment: I'm checking login code from this period and this is correct "The way MVC5 is setup right now is half-baked and broken, for no apparent reason.".  AFAIKT The fix would appear to be to include code that sends a confirmation code email, as done by the local account method.